# confused with a variable within a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, variables

```
int getTo(int value)
{
    int total{};

    for (int count{ 1 }; count <= value; ++count)
        total += count;
    return total;

}

int main()
{
    getTo(5);
    return 0;
}
```

first time post, please excuse any formatting issues.

im struggling to understand where the variable total is used within this for loop, where it is getting its value from to be able to later manipulate it. Is there some analogy that may make this easier to understand?

Comment: What the getTo functiuon is doing is taking an int as its function parameter, with main providing the number 5. It then returns the value of 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15.

Comment: If you want to add information to your question please don't do it in the comments section, where it is easily overlooked. You can always [edit] your question ;)

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run this code at a speed that a human mind can handle and watch the program's state, the variables, change in real time. For example, you could single step through the program, executing each line (or instruction if you need to get that fine-a-grain to understand what happened) one at a time. The debugger is one of the best programmer productivity tools available, and the sooner you get used to using them, the sooner you can reap the benefits.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful replies, I was not expecting that! After reading through the comments and stepping through it with the debugger as someone suggested it became a lot more apparent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `getTo()`, `total` is first default-initialized (meaning that it takes a value of `0`).

The `for-loop` sets a variable `count = 1`, then constantly increments it until it reaches `value`, adding it to `total` each iteration. For `getTo(5)`, it would do this:

1. `getTo(5)` initializes `total` to 0
2. `getTo(5)` initializes `count` to 1

   `count = 1`, so add `1` to `total`, --> `total = 1` now, increment `count`

   `count = 2`, so add `2` to `total`, --> `total = 3` now, increment `count`

   `count = 3`, so add `3` to `total`, --> `total = 6` now, increment `count`

   `count = 4`, so add `4` to `total`, --> `total = 10` now, increment `count`

   `count = 5`, so add `5` to `total`, --> `total = 15` now, increment `count`
3. `getTo(5)` returns `total`, which is equal to `15`.

Answer (score 0):

> im struggling to understand where the variable total is used within
> this for loop, where it is getting its value from to be able to later
> manipulate it. Is there some analogy that may make this easier to
> understand?

```
int total{};
//       ^^
```

The curly braces default-initialize the variable `total` to `0`

The function then sums the values from 1 to 5 and stores it in `total`.

Answer (score 0):

The empty initializer in the `int total{};` declaration initializes the variable to zero, just like `int total(0);` or `int total = 0;`

Similary, the initializer in `int count{ 1 };` is equivalent to `int count(1);`; or `int count = 1;`